# How to extract only the time from DateTime.now();

Tags: flutter, dart

I've this variables to extract the time from `DateTime.now();`

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String time = "${date.hour}:${date.minute}:${date.second}";
```

The problem is if the time for example is 01:09:32, the time that i get is 1:9:32.

How do i get the time with the regular format?

I can do this with if-else, but i'm sure there is a better way

Comment: In general, you can do `'$x'.padLeft(2, '0')` to force a string representation of `x` with at least two digits with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can try to use a DateFormat, just include [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) dependency to your pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(now);
print(formattedTime);
```

Depending on what your requirements is, you can look at [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Some examples taken from DateFormat-class to help you a bit more.

```
String formattedTime = DateFormat.jm().format(now);           //5:08 PM
String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hm().format(now);           //17:08  force 24 hour time
```

Answer (score 2):

Create this function in your Utility Mixin if you have otherwise you can create it in your class also

```
String getTimeFromDateAndTime(String date) {
    DateTime dateTime;
    try {
      dateTime = DateTime.parse(date).toLocal();
      return DateFormat.jm().format(dateTime).toString(); //5:08 PM
// String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(now);
// String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hm().format(now);   // //17:08  force 24 hour time
    }
    catch (e) {
    return date;
    }
  }
```

// In your class

```
getTimeFromDateAndTime("Pass date in string here")
```

- Uncomment format whichever you want from the try part.
- Use try and catch is a must, because sometime you will get a crash when the format will not match

Answer (score 1):

You can extract it and also use the TimeofDay Object by using this:

```
TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now());
```