Get full time from '2024-07-22 04:55:00.000+0230' in flutter
I want just time from '2024-07-22 04:55:00.000+0230' output in flutter. taking this from above full date and time just 04:55 or 4:55.

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427418/how-to-extract-only-the-time-from-datetime-now

This question is similar to: How to extract only the time from DateTime.now();. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Exactly this is not similar, I got this content '2024-07-22 04:55:00.000+0230' from package prayers_times/prayers_times.dart' and and its method prayerTime.fajrEndTime then i got this date. now i want just it is time 04:55 or 4:55.

and for more information this is not coming from DateTime.now(), this came from prayerTime.fajrEndTime method, now how to get its time?

I don't think there is a more direct way of doing it than using the ".hour", ".minute" and ".second".
Like this:
DateTime data = DateTime.now();

print("${data.hour}:${data.minute}:${data.second}");

Hope it'll solve your problem

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
